# If condition to make second slideshow on floating div work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make a second slideshow on a floating layer. However, the main slideshow stopped working. I can't make both work at the same time. I believe I must do an "if" condition to make the second slideshow only work when the floating div is visible or active. But I don't know how to do this.

This is the original code for the main slideshow:

```
var imgs = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') { // left
        changeImage(-1);![1]
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') { // right
        changeImage(1);
    }
}

function changeImage(dir) {
    var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + dir] || imgs[(dir==1) ? 0 : imgs.length-1];
    var index = imgs.indexOf(img.src);
};
```

I have tried an if condition like this, for the second slideshow to work only when the floating layer in which it is contained is active, but I can't get it right.

```
if ($("#floatingLayer").is(":visible") == true) { 
    ORIGINAL SLIDESHOW CODE ABOVE 
};
```

If it helps, this is the code to toggle the floating layer:

```
function ToggleFloatingLayer(DivID){
    $('#' + DivID).fadeToggle(0);
};
```

Can anyone help me? I want the original layer to be working by default but to stop when I toggle the floating layer on. Then only the second slideshow should work.
Thank you

Comment: By writing the whole thing as a Constructor or a jQuery plugin, you can make each invocation independent of all others.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I do that?

Comment: A constructor is just a function that (a) is called with keyword `new` and (b) uses `this` internally to refer to the instance. For jQuery plugins, [start here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). It's really beyond the remit of StackOverflow to say more. This is the sort of stuff that, having been pointed in the right direction, you should research yourself. Then by all means ask specific questions when you get into difficulty.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for better understanding ?